# wordpress forms submit

Tags: forms

I am new to wordpress. I am trying to develop a website where I want user registration form. But I am not sure how should I code in wordpress. I heard about some contact form plugins. Can someone direct me to some good tutorial or post about how to work with form submits in wordpress?

Comment: What kind of form is it gonna be? I mean, what fields are gonna be there? Some good plugins are available, but it depends a lot on your task. You could also code the form as a template, and parse it as you would parse a form in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

To create form in wordpress there are two ways either use plugins or custom templates.

If you want good plugin to create form then contact for 7 is the best.

Url: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Website: http://contactform7.com/

Documentation: http://contactform7.com/docs/

To create custom template:

Url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

> If you want contact form then check this out :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

> or if you want registration form then check this out :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplr-registration-form/